# Spotfire - what is the equivalent of Oracle Decode?

Tags: sql, spotfire

I'm trying to replicate the equivalent of:

```
select name, salary, decode(salary > 100, "Nice Job", job) as job
from blah...


blah table being:
name
salary
job
```

Is there an equivalent of decode or if or switch or something?

Comment: Try using the `case` statement.  That is the ANSI standard expression for conditional logic.

Comment: Hmmm.  Failed to get data: Bad value for type long : Engineer        It's as if the result of the case statement is expected to be a long and is failing as a string is being returned.  Any suggestions?

Comment: result of case statement can be a string according to this example: case when 1 < 2 then "a" when 1 < 3 then "b" else "c" end  which is located here: http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/ncfe/ncfe_logical_functions.htm

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select name, salary, case when salary > 100 then "Nice Job" else job end as job
from blah...
```

Answer (score 1):

If `job` is an integer, you need to convert it to a string:

```
select (case when salary > 100 then "Nice Job" else cast(job as varchar(255))
        end) as job
```